# How to put ImagePicker into a view container?

Tags: ios, swift

[EDIT]: I've got it working by simply calling addSubview. Also got it properly located in my container view using constraints. However clicking the buttons to take a picture or invert the camera doesn't work. Any suggestions?

I'm using https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker and I wanted to embed it inside a view container. So I added a container view in storyboard, it automatically created a UIViewController for me to use as embedded. I've assigned a class to that new UIViewController and trying to add imagePickerController inside it:

```
class mainViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

   ....
}


class containerViewController: UIViewController, ImagePickerDelegate {
    lazy var imagePickerController: ImagePickerController = ImagePickerController()

    func wrapperDidPress(images: [UIImage]) {
        print("wrapperDidPress")
    }
    func doneButtonDidPress(images: [UIImage]) {
        print("doneDidPress")
    }

    func cancelButtonDidPress() {
        print("cancelDidPress")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        self.addChildViewController(imagePickerController)
        imagePickerController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePickerController.delegate = self
    }
}
```

As the result I'm getting just an empty container view without ImagePicker. What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you need to say something like: `self.view.addSubview(imagePickerController.view)` in containerViewController's viewDidAppear after addChildViewController and before didMoveToParentViewController

Comment: Yeah that works. I believe I've tried but it didn't work before for some reason. Thanks.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to fit it inside the view? I only see a corner of ImagePickerController. I tried imagePickercontroller.view.bounds = view.bounds and it didn't help

Comment: I'm pretty positive the intention is to have it take over the screen, hence why they suggest using `presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thanks I have it working in full screen mode just fine and it works great. Now I have another task - to embed it.

Comment: Also I can't seem to press  the buttons in embedded view